# How do I add indexes to a MySQL table when creating a new table from a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am creating a new table in a database called 'production' by joining data from two tables in another database called 'crawler'.  I create this new table with the following SQL query ( this query works perfectly ):

```
CREATE TABLE files_and_metas_joined
SELECT
    crawler.files.id,
    crawler.files.company_id,
    crawler.file_metas.title,
    crawler.file_metas.h1_tags
FROM
    crawler.files,
    crawler.file_metas
WHERE
    crawler.files.id = crawler.file_metas.file_id
    AND
    crawler.files.processed = 1
    AND
    crawler.files.junk = 0
```

I'd like to also add the following indexes to this table but can't seem to figure out how to do it in the same SQL query.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
KEY `title` (`title`),
KEY `h1_tags` (`h1_tags`)
```

Can this be done in the same query used to create the table?  If not, how do I add these indexes with a query afterwards?

Comment: Afterwards: [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the same statement, they just have to go before the `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE files_and_metas_joined
(
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  KEY `h1_tags` (`h1_tags`)
)
SELECT
    crawler.files.id,
    crawler.files.company_id,
    crawler.file_metas.title,
    crawler.file_metas.h1_tags
FROM
    crawler.files,
    crawler.file_metas
WHERE
    crawler.files.id = crawler.file_metas.file_id
    AND
    crawler.files.processed = 1
    AND
    crawler.files.junk = 0
```